# how to fetch line from array of strings in a row in mysql

Tags: mysql

this is server_var_dump row one output http://pastebin.com/e1qHG64Q
now how do I query to get just the HTTP_USER_AGENT line and save it in separate field?
I have done this with php script but I want to do it with mysql query so that it will be fast because the database is huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE your_table
SET user_agent = SUBSTR(server_var_dump, 
        @p, INSTR(SUBSTR(server_var_dump, @p, 100), "\n")-1)
WHERE @p := INSTR(server_var_dump,'[HTTP_USER_AGENT]')+21;
```

Comment: #1193 - Unknown system variable 'user_agent'

Comment: ak i made this changes like this @user_agent. but now i get this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE @p:= INSTR(server_var_dump,'[HTTP_USER_AGENT]')+21' at line 3

Comment: You gave me little to go on. `user_agent` was meant to be the field in your table that you wanted to update with the actual user agent string. Your question just stated 'in separate field'. The only variable I use there is `@p`

Comment: hmmm that worked.. I had to add user_agent field in that table ( earlier it wasn't there ) . Now another issue.. HTTP_USER_AGENT doesn't lie in 22nd row in all the outputs... so some of the rows in field user_agent are blank :( . now isn't there way to fetch the rown if it matches HTTP_USER_AGENT? please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer too. :) thought would be useful for others:

```
UPDATE tablename SET useragent= SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(server_var_dump,INSTR(server_var_dump,'[HTTP_USER_AGENT]')+21,200), '[', 1);
```

how? substring_index fetches the substring until the first occurence of "[" delimeter defined. and substring defined is beginning from [HTTP_USER_AGENT]+21 +21 TO remove the [HTTP_USER_AGENT] stuff. now we have clean just what we want is useragent. :)
now I have one doubt. if I update this to entire column. will the update be corrosponding to the server_var_dump row which we fetched user_agent from ? or it ll just update from first ?